# MySQL & Laravel: How to include my custom derived column in where clauses?

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a function that filters users based on varied criteria. One of the filters is based on user net worth. In the database, we currently only store net assets, and net debt, and calculating net worth is simply subtracting debt from assets.

My filter function needs to be able to find users under a target number, over a target number, or between two target numbers.

In Eloquent code, here is what I have.

```
//more code before...
// filter net worth
        ->when(isset($request_filter_params['minNetWorth']) 
            || isset($request_filter_params['maxNetWorth']), fn ($query) => 
            $query->whereHas('net_worth_estimate_calc_response', fn ($q) => 
                $q->select(DB::raw('(net_worth_estimate_asset - net_worth_estimate_debt) as net_worth'))
                    ->when(isset($request_filter_params['minNetWorth']), fn ($qq) => 
                        $qq->where('net_worth', '>=', $request_filter_params['minNetWorth'])
                    )
                    ->when(isset($request_filter_params['maxNetWorth']), fn ($qqq) => 
                        $qqq->where('net_worth', '<=', $request_filter_params['maxNetWorth'])
                    )
            )
        )
//more code after...
```

The SQL it produces:

```
select
    *
from
    `users`
where
    and `is_active` = 1
    and `is_groupadmin` = 0
    and exists (
    select
        (net_worth_estimate_asset - net_worth_estimate_debt) as net_worth
    from
        `user_net_worth_estimate_calculator_responses`
    where
        `users`.`id` = `user_net_worth_estimate_calculator_responses`.`user_id`
        and `net_worth` >= 2500
        and `net_worth` <= 10000)
order by
    `updated_at` desc
```

That sql produces the error `Unknown column 'net_worth' in 'where clause'`.

Clearly caused by my custom `DB::raw('(net_worth_estimate_asset - net_worth_estimate_debt) as net_worth')` call, is there any way to allow filtering in the where clauses based on this derived value? Or is this something MySQL cant do and I have to move this into the PHP layer (which I would love to avoid)?

Edit: 'user_net_worth_estimate_calculator_responses' only has `user_id (bigint)`, `net_worth_estimate_asset (double)`, `net_worth_estimate_debt (double`, a PK `id` and a couple of timestamps. The Model file is a completely standard eloquent model.

Comment: show the tables/models also

Comment: ```net_worth_estimate_asset - net_worth_estimate_debt``` is this a computation?

Comment: It is, yes. @Newbee

Comment: Then, don't do this ```$q->select(DB::raw('(net_worth_estimate_asset - net_worth_estimate_debt) as net_worth'))```

Comment: Any suggestions what to use instead? `net_worth` doesn't exist otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with *having*:

```
$qq->having('net_worth', '>=', $request_filter_params['minNetWorth'])
```

or alternatively with *whereRaw* (this *should* have better performance)

```
$qq->whereRaw('net_worth_estimate_asset - net_worth_estimate_debt >= ?', $request_filter_params['minNetWorth'])
```

Comment: Wow! Yep `->having()` worked immediately! Thanks. Any explanation of the difference?

Comment: *Having* requires an internal secondary query something like: `SELECT ... FROM SELECT (...) WHERE ...` and some SQL engine might not support it for this situation, while the *whereRaw* pattern is more linear but probably executes the subtraction multiple times

Comment: The general order where he database will get your result is something like "filter the table down to what you need (the WHEREs) > do your grouping (if you use GROUP BY) > calculate the projections (the SELECT bit) > filter the groups. (the HAVING bit)". So in the WHERE conditions the SELECT aliases don't exist yet